# Django admin problems

Tags: python, django

I have the following stack trace when trying to access the django admin default app. Does anyone know how to fix it? I have defined the field `date_created` clearly in my models.py for the catalog app. I'm not sure where else I need to define it?

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin

'ProductAdmin.exclude' refers to field 'date_created' that is missing from the form.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    

'ProductAdmin.exclude' refers to field 'date_created' that is missing from the form.

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py in check_formfield, line 362
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.1
Python Path:    

['/Users/christopherfarm/Desktop/ecomstore',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django_db_log-2.2.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']

Server time:    Mon, 31 Oct 2011 16:02:11 -0500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you've set `auto_now_add` or `auto_add` in your `models.py` field, thus it's not a part of your form in the first place to exclude.

Try removing it from your exclude statement.

Comment: yes I have it there. What exactly does it do and why is it throwing the error?

Comment: Because you are trying to exclude a field that isn't a part of your admin form. By default, certain fields are not added to a modelform. You can't exclude what's not there ; ) If you want to see it, add it to `readonly_fields`

Comment: but what i'm confused with is if it's defined clearly in the models.py, then why is it not able to be used in admin.py after i import the classes?

Comment: As I said, by default, some fields are not automatically added to the admin form. If a field is set to add a timestamp at creation, it's not meant to be modified. If you would like to see them in the admin form, use `readonly_fields`. If you would like to edit them, override the admin form and explicitly add the field to your `forms.Form`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the change after the initial `syncdb`? If so, you need to do a `reset` on the app in question so that the tables get dropped, re-created, and (if you have fixtures) reloaded.

Alternatively, you can go into the `dbshell` for your app and alter the table yourself using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same error. I came back to the project I was not dealing with for a while. And I run it with `django==1.5` instead of `django==1.6` on which is was working.

so to summarize in my case it was connected with django version on `1.5` I got error like:
`ExhibitorAdmin.exclude' refers to field 'collectedcontact' that is missing from the form.`

while, when switching to `django==1.6` this problem for me disappears immediately.